# Get extends keyword to work in a local gitlabci runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
.fromz:
  script: echo "foo"
  image: node:10-alpine

tryit:
  extends: fromz
```

trying it with gitlab runner from master - here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/install/bleeding-edge.md#download-the-standalone-binaries

`gitlab-runner-linux-amd64 exec docker tryit`

Result:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=18273 revision=54ee8e8c version=11.6.0~beta.881.g54ee8e8c
FATAL: missing 'script' for job
```

What do I need to get `extends` to work?

Comment: I hope this is not the only possible answer: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3794

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `extends: .fromz` instead of `extends: fromz`.

The "hidden jobs" (leading dot) and the `extends` features are two separate features, just they work well nicely together. If I'm not mistaken, you could probably also extend from non-hidden jobs, i.e. jobs without a leading dot, therefore it makes sense that you *do* have to write the dot explicitly, since it's just part of the job name.